# Ionic 3 in-app purchase2 do not show products

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

To begin, I have set up my app in google play console. I have added it in alpha closed testing also. And my install my billing license with the plugin. I currently testing it in android only. I used the **'android.test.purchased'** as for google [instructions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing)

I have followed and tried every example I can see.

But the problem is when I click the button upgrade (non-consumable purchase). Nothing happens, no popup from my native device showing price or something. Maybe I missed something in implementation.

Please help me check my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppPurchase2, IAPProduct  } from '@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-offer',
  templateUrl: 'offer.html',
})
export class OfferPage {

  public product: any = {
    name: 'Upgrade to Pro',
    appleProductId: 'android.test.purchased',
    googleProductId: 'android.test.purchased'
  };

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public platform: Platform,
    public store: InAppPurchase2
    ) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.configurePurchasing();
      });

  }

  configurePurchasing() {
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return; }
    let productId;
    try {
      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        productId = this.product.appleProductId;
      } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        productId = this.product.googleProductId;
      }

      // Register Product
      // Set Debug High
      this.store.verbosity = this.store.DEBUG;

      // Register the product with the store
      this.store.register({
        id: productId,
        alias: productId,
        type: this.store.NON_CONSUMABLE
      });

      this.registerHandlers(productId);

      InAppPurchase2.getPlugin().ready().then((status) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.store.get(productId)));
        console.log('Store is Ready: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
        console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));

      });

      // Errors On The Specific Product
      this.store.when(productId).error( (error) => {
        alert('An Error Occured' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
      // Refresh Always
      console.log('Refresh Store');
      this.store.refresh();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error On Store Issues' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }

  registerHandlers(productId) {
    // Handlers
    this.store.when(productId).approved( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      // Purchase was approved
      product.finish();
    });

    this.store.when(productId).registered( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      console.log('Registered: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
    });

    this.store.when(productId).updated( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      console.log('Loaded' + JSON.stringify(product));
    });

    this.store.when(productId).cancelled( (product) => {
      alert('Purchase was Cancelled');
    });

    // Overall Store Error
    this.store.error( (err) => {
      alert('Store Error ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }

  async purchase() {
    /* Only configuring purchase when you want to buy, because when you configure a purchase
    It prompts the user to input their apple id info on config which is annoying */
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return };

    let productId;

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      productId = this.product.appleProductId;
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      productId = this.product.googleProductId;
    }

    console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));
    console.log('Ordering From Store: ' + productId);
    try {
      let product = this.store.get(productId);
      console.log('Product Info: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
      let order = await this.store.order(productId);
      alert('Finished Purchase');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error Ordering ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Did u ever make it work?

Comment: Yes, it seems that you need to test it in beta testing first the sign the app to make it work.